# R: extract latitude from raster

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster

How to I extract or subset a raster object to just one row of data? I have a raster of global temperature data and want to calculate the mean monthly value per year for each longitude/column.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

download.file("http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/temperature/CRUTEM.4.3.0.0.anomalies.nc"
              , destfile="CRUTEM.4.3.0.0.anomalies.nc", mode="wb")

cru.tmp <-  stack("CRUTEM.4.3.0.0.anomalies.nc")

# inspect elements
cru.tmp

# list all years
names(cru.tmp)

# plot a single year
plot(cru.tmp$X2008.01.16)

# find nrow for 67.5deg North
mylat <- rowFromY(cru.tmp, 67.5)

# extract the row
cru.tmp.67.5N <- getValuesBlock(test, row=mylat, nrows=1)
```

So basically I want for each of the 72 remaining grid cells 12 monthly means.

Comment: Perhaps convert each raster layer to a matrix (e.g. `as.matrix(cru.tmp$X1850.01.16)`) to make it easier to get to the data you need? `crop` could also work, but that may be a slow operation.

Comment: I'm one step further using `getValuesBlock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use basic indexing to get a single row or column.

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x4 <- b[,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is already in `cru.tmp.67.5N`, but needs rearranging:

```
cru.tmp.67.5N_mean <- array(NA, c(72,12,165))

colnames(cru.tmp.67.5N_mean) <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
                    "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
rownames(cru.tmp.67.5N_mean) <- xFromCol(cru.tmp, col=1:ncol(cru.tmp))

for (i in 1:12){
  for (j in 1:72){
    for (k in 1:165){

    month <- seq(i,length(colnames(cru.tmp.67.5N)),12)
    cru.tmp.67.5N_mean[j,i,k] <- cru.tmp.67.5N[j,month[k]]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: not quite correct logic, that's the mean of all years, instead of the mean for each year...

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation is straightforward to do from the command line using cdo:

```
cdo monmean -zonmean CRUTEM.4.3.0.0.anomalies.nc  monzonmean.nc
```

The zonmean calculates the zonal mean which is then piped to the monmean command.  This is for all years, but if you want a particular year then you can use the selyear command, e.g:

```
cdo monmean -zonmean -selyear,2008 CRUTEM.4.3.0.0.anomalies.nc  monzonmean2008.nc
```